# k items in N buckets. Number of buckets with at least 2 items?

Tags: probability

I've got the following problem:

> You've got $k$ items in $N$ buckets. What is the average number of 
>   buckets $c$ that contain at least $2$ items?

I think that the average number of buckets containing at least 1 item can be calculated like this:
$$d = \left(1-\left(1-\frac1N\right)^k\right)\cdot N$$

$k$ buckets would be full if there were no collisions so $k-d$ must be the number of items in a bucket with at least another. So I guess the number of items with at least $2$ collisions is

$$e = \left(1-\left(1-\frac1d \right)^{k-d} \right)\cdot d$$

Am I right ? Does this problem have a name that I can search for on the internet ?

Additional: How can I calculate the number if the probability for an item to be in a bucket isn't equally distributed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think there does not exist a simple formula.

Look at the [generalized birthday problem](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath057.htm) and [another](http://rigelkent.blogspot.in/2010/05/mckinneys-generalization-of-birthday.html)

For the notation you have used, the probability can be written as:

$\displaystyle
\mathbb{P}(\text{part})=\dfrac{\displaystyle N!\, k!}{\displaystyle k^N\, \prod_{t=0}^N\, a_t!\, t!^{\displaystyle a_t}}
$

where $a_t$ is the number of buckets with exactly $t$ items. Here, 'part' is one of the possible partitions and $N\ge k$.

E.g. If $N=5$ and $k=4$, the probability of getting a partition of {2,2,0,0,0} is

$
\mathbb{P}(\{2,2,0,0,0\})=\dfrac{5!4!}{4^5\, (3!0!^3\; 2!2!^2)}=\dfrac{12}{125}
$

As for your formula, the second formula does not get the right answer.

To compare, when $N=30$ and $k=10$, the $d$ matches with the expected value derived from the probabilities.

But $e\approx 1.34358355016239$ is close, but does not match with the exact value

$\mathbb{E}(\text{at least 2 items})=\dfrac{8237102313703}{6561000000000}\approx 1.25546445872626$